# Angular stripe add card form allow only one enter button submit

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I have an angular add stripe card form and it is working fine. However I need to add a funcationality for this card to be submitted with an enter button click if all fields are correct. So I decided to add a `keyup.enter` functionality that just call the function `stripeCard.createToken` and this function also gets called on clicking save button via mouse. But if I press enter key immediately 3 times then it adds 3 cards instead of one. How can I stop this from happening? I tried to reset form right after token creation too but it just doesn't work. Here is my form code

P.S I am just going to add a few lines of form as I think that all that's required.

```
<div class="add-card-module" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
    <form [formGroup]="paymentForm" appDebounceSubmit (debounceSubmit)="stripeCard.createToken();" (keyup.enter)="stripeCard.createToken()">
        <div class="form-group curnt-plan-box">
            <div class="px-3">
                <div class="text-left">
                    <h4 class="mt-4 mb-3">Add Debit or credit Card</h4>
                    <div class="card-types">
                        <ul class="d-inline-flex" type="none">
                            <li class="mr-2"><a><img src="assets/images/visa-img.svg" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li class="mr-2"><a><img src="assets/images/master-card.svg" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li class="mr-2"><a><img src="assets/images/amex.svg" alt=""></a></li>
                            <li class="mr-2"><a><img src="assets/images/discover-network.svg" alt=""></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group search-box my-3 position-relative">
                    <img src="assets/images/user-gray.svg" alt="" class="user-name" />
                    <input class="form-control" alphabetAndSpaceOnly type="text" formControlName="nameOnCard" placeholder="Name on card" />
                    <label class="d-none">Name on card</label>
                </div>
```

Comment: any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to add code that will prevent the function you're trying to call from firing multiple times.  Simplified example:

```
var formSubmissionInProgress = false;

function submitForm() {
  if (formSubmissionInProgress) { return; }

  formSubmissionInProgress = true;

  // Handle form submission here
  // Call stripeCard.createToken(), etc.

  // If an error is encountered or you otherwise
  // need to allow form submission again set
  // formSubmissionInProgress to false again
}
```

Then call `submitForm()` in the code you shared in your question instead of `stripeCard.createToken()` directly.